# SQL querying - counting from two tables by weekday

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have the two following (MySQL) tables called "Jobs" and "Employees_Jobs:

Jobs:

```
job_id     job_creation_date
     1     2016-01-01   
     2     2016-01-02
```

Employees_Jobs (job applications):

```
EJ_job_id  EJ_creation_date
        1  2016-01-02
        2  2016-01-02
        2  2016-01-03
```

I want MySQL returning the number of jobs created, **and** the number of job applications created **per day of the week**; taking the above data it should return:

```
weekday  num_of_jobs_entered  num_of_applications_entered
Friday   1                    0
Saturday 1                    2     // corrected from  1
Sunday   0                    1     //                 2
```

I now have the following query:

```
SELECT
    DAYNAME(job_creation_date) as weekday,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Jobs) as num_of_jobs_entered,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employees_Jobs) as num_of_applications_entered
FROM 
    dual
GROUP BY 
    weekday
ORDER BY 
    weekday;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: In your subqueries you have been counting *all* jobs and *all* Employees_Jobs, regardless of their weekday. See my answer below for a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT wd, COUNT(jcnt), COUNT(ecnt) FROM
 (SELECT DAYNAME(job_creation_date) wd, 1 jcnt, null ecnt FROM Jobs UNION ALL
  SELECT DAYNAME(EJ_creation_date),  null,         1      FROM Employees_Jobs ) a
GROUP BY wd
```

See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cef1b/6) for a working example.

**EDIT**

If I understand you correctly you want to divide the above calculated counts of job offers and requirements by the current week number of the current year (which will make sense of course only if all considered job counts have also occurred in the current year -> some filtering might become necessary).

However, whithout the filtering you could do

```
SELECT week_day, Week(CURDATE()) weekCurrdate,
   COUNT(num_of_jobs_entered)/Week(CURDATE()) avg_of_jobs_entered,
   COUNT(num_of_applications_entered)/Week(CURDATE()) avg_num_of_applications_entered 
FROM (
  SELECT DAYNAME(job_creation_date) week_day, 1 num_of_jobs_entered,
  null num_of_applications_entered FROM Jobs UNION ALL 
  SELECT DAYNAME(EJ_creation_date), null, 1 FROM Employees_Jobs ) A
GROUP BY week_day;
```

The `IFNULL()` function is obsolete but you will *have* to use `COUNT()` instead in the outer `select`. Since the current week number is `1` at the moment the result from this query will (presently!) be identical to the one of the previous query, see modified [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cef1b/20).

Comment: Thank you! it works, but i have a problem understanding your solution. what does the "1" in the subquery stands for? i have never seen anything like it before

Comment: It does not matter *what* you put into the column list of the subquery. You could use any valid column too - the result and the performance will be the same. To illustrate that I am not interested in the actual column value but only the existance of a record I used `1`. In the outer `SELECT` I `count` the occurences of valid values.

Comment: one last thing, i altered your solution so it will fit another query - I want MySQL returning the  **average** number of jobs created, and the  **average** number of job applications created per day of the week; i'm new here so i will add the code I wrote in the next comment. my question is - is it also OK to use 1 to illustrate that I am not interested in the actual column in this query? thank you so much for your help

Comment: `SELECT week_day, IFNULL(num_of_jobs_entered/Week(CURDATE()),0) AS avg_of_jobs_entered, IFNULL(num_of_applications_entered/Week(CURDATE()),0) AS avg_num_of_applications_entered
FROM
 (SELECT DAYNAME(job_creation_date) AS week_day, 1 AS num_of_jobs_entered, null AS num_of_applications_entered 
 FROM Jobs
 UNION ALL
  SELECT DAYNAME(EJ_creation_date), null, 1      
 FROM Employees_Jobs ) as A
GROUP BY week_day;`